# Set legacy database in Aegir context

Tags: drush, migrations, aegir

Im fairly new to aegir and I have some hard time finding out the proper way to set a legacy database in aegir context. As far as I can see settings.php inside a platform is automatically generated so if I edit this file and run verify all changes will be lost. Other option is to insert it into drushrc file but Im still not sure what the syntax should be there. I see that database is inside the options array. Anyone with similar experience and few advice how to tackle this properly?

Comment: The voting and flagging on this question is bizarre - it's pretty clear what's being asked, it's not spam (please stop flagging it as such, you know who you are), I really don't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such definitions can be placed in a `local.settings.php` file, alongside the generated `settings.php`.

You'll find an include statement at the bottom of the generated `settings.php`

Comment: I managed to find it several minutes after posting the question but thanks a lot for the answer. It is bizarre for me too why people just down vote even if it is simple questions - answer would be one line. I am going through the whole documentation but I didnt saw that part with local.settings.php